# Handling Many-to-Many Relationships in Go with GORM While Avoiding Circular Dependencies

Tags: go, domain-driven-design, go-gorm, circular-dependency

I have two primary domain entities, User and Project, which have a many-to-many relationship. When I tried to reference each from the other (i.e., a slice of Projects in User and a slice of Users in Project), I ended up with a circular dependency in my package structure.Here's a simplified version of my models:

```
// in user package
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    ...
    Projects []project.Project `gorm:"many2many:user_projects;"`
}

// in project package
type Project struct {
    gorm.Model
    ...
    Users []user.User `gorm:"many2many:user_projects;"`
}
```

I understand why the circular dependency occurs, but I'm struggling with the best way to restructure my code to maintain this many-to-many relationship while keeping things idiomatic in Go.Some solutions I've considered:

- Dropping the reference back from Project to User.
- Introducing an intermediary UserProject type (essentially representing the join table).
- Using interfaces.

What's the idiomatic way to handle such situations in Go? Any pointers or examples would be highly appreciated!Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to move all models to separate package, e.g.:

```
package model

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    ...
    Projects []Project `gorm:"many2many:user_projects;"`
}

type Project struct {
    gorm.Model
    ...
    Users []User `gorm:"many2many:user_projects;"`
}
```

Package User:

```
package user
...
func SetUser(user *model.User) {
 ...
}
```

Package Project:

```
package Project
...
func SetProject(project *model.Project) {
 ...
}
```